# NodeJS Soap Client

Tags: node.js, soap

I've been working on a script that sends and reads data from and to a SOAP server. I've been doing it pretty simple with the requests module. However, this isn't really ideal for me. So, I've decided to try and use the soap module. This is my current code:

```
var soap = require("soap");
function fetch2(actor) {
    var uri = `http://moviestarplanet.com/Webservice/User/UserService.asmx?wsdl`;
    soap.createClient(uri, {}, function(err, client) {
        client.GetActorIdByName({ actorName: actor }, function(err, result) {
            console.log(err, result);
        });
    });
}
```

However, this is giving an error and I feel like its because it is important to pass http headers. In my old requests function, I used to pass the following headers

```
"User-Agent":"Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; GT-I9505 Build/KOT49H)",
"Content-Length": xmlData.length,
"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1",
```

So how can I pass http headers with my soap client?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom header like below

`client.addHttpHeader('User-Agent',`CustomUserAgent`);`

For more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#extra-headers-optional